# How to end a loop with a function?

Tags: c++

```
void Stop() {
    break;
}

int main() {

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "NO!" << '\n';
        Stop();
    }
    std::cout << "YES!";
}
```

In my project I need to end `while` using a function, how can I change this uncompilable example?

I have an idea to use `throw`, but what about other better solutions?

Comment: Why do you need to have the function break the loop? The function shouldn't have to care whether it is called inside a loop or not. So how can it specifically break a loop? What should it do when it is _not_ called inside a loop? What is the specific purpose of the function?

Comment: Note that if this were allowed, it would make code extremely hard to read / understand.

Comment: @Yves Daoust In my project, there is an object that has a function that performs the action of the object. The action returns back to the menu, and to do this you need to stop the loop.

Comment: `bool stopping = false;` `void Stop() {stopping = true;}` I'm sure you can figure out the third part

Comment: @user253751 The thing is, it's pointless to use a function, you just have to set the `stopping` variable directly, especially if it's meant to be made from inside the loop.

Comment: It sounds like you need to think some more about your design and change it instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: I think the question itself is a good beginner question, however the idea to use a function as substitute for `break` keyword is bad. Take the advice from the answers below and just go for `if (shouldStop()) break;`

Comment: do
    {
      ...
    }
    while (not Stop());

is a possible solution.

Comment: If you truly are into defining your own language and have difficult-to-maintain code, the C++ PreProcessor lets you do this `#define Stop() break` (this is one of the reasons I minimize use of `#define` in C++)

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's an unfair XY problem accusation. This is the way the human mind things about the task.  I call a function called Stop, and during the coding of that function I find myself needing to have that other loop I coded elsewhere exit. It's fair to ask if something exists within the language to express this concicely rather than be faced with the potentially slightly larger task of refactoring a control mechanism into the outer loop.  `break` _seems_ like the right thing, but the asker has identified that it doesn't work in a nested function.  I think it's a fair (beginner) question.

Comment: @Wyck: understand that reporting an XY problem is no *accusation* (?) but a hint to the OP that he should consider explaining the problem from a higher perspective or confirm that this weird requirement is a *must*.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really do this. Using exceptions for managing control flow and business logic is considered to be a bad practice in **any** programming language. What you can do, you could return a boolean flag for breaking out of the loop, for example, when this condition is too complex to be coded directly in the loop:

```
bool Stop(int idx) {
    return idx > 10;
}

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "NO!" << '\n';
        const bool is_invalid = Stop(counter);

        if (is_invalid) break;
        ++counter;
    }
    std::cout << "YES!";
}
```

Comment: _"Using exceptions [...]"_ But OP didn't use exceptions. Other thing, the proposed design is horribly bad, no offense. The problem is why using a function ? Why an infinite loop ? Your whole mecanism could be replaced by a simpler, more readable, more concise and more efficient `for(int counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter) {}`. If the stop condition is more complex, you could indeed use a function to perform the evaluation, but it should be called/evaluated in the `while()` (of `for()`) argument, not inside the body. That's where the running condition is meant to be evaluated, how loop works.

Comment: OP asked about throwing to get out of the loop, so I commented on that. I would agree with you in this particular case - yes, it could be replaced with good old for loop, yes, design could be better. But the question was how to break out of the loop from within the function **in general** and I believe that my answer is pretty complete on that. As breaking within the condition or within the body of the loop - I think its a matter of taste. If you have multiple exit conditions, for example, it makes total sense to evaluate them within the body - it's just easier to follow, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, but it's not good design. Take it with a grain of salt, it's just to demonstrate what you need to change to make it work.

```cpp
bool isRunning = false;

void Stop() {
    isRunnning = false;
}

int main() {

    isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning) {
        std::cout << "NO!" << '\n';
        Stop();
    }
    std::cout << "YES!";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the function return the value of the stop condition. I suppose this is a simplified example. In a real example the function would take parameters and either return `true` or `false` (if it always stops the loop unconditionally, then there is no need for a loop in the first place, hence also no need for the function to stop the loop):

```
bool Stop() {
    return false;
}

int main() {

    do  {
        std::cout << "NO!" << '\n';
    } while ( Stop() );
    std::cout << "YES!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar by having control over things.

```
class Server {
public:
    Server() = default;
    
    void start() {
        loop();
    }
    
    
    void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
    
private:
    void loop() {
        while (isRunning) {
            // stop whenever you want
        }
    }
    
private:
    bool isRunning = true;
};


int main() {
    Server sv;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a bool variable for the infinite loop and change it by reference from some function:

```
#include <iostream>

void Stop(bool& running) {
    running = false;
}

int main() {

    bool running = true;

    while (running) {
      // ...
      std::cout << "inside loop" << std::endl;
      Stop(running);
    }

    std::cout << "outside loop" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```